# Accessing hive data using spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I want access hive data using spark:

```
%spark
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)

sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS src (key INT, value STRING)")
sqlContext.sql(LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '//filepath' INTO TABLE src)

sqlContext.sql("FROM src SELECT key, value").collect().foreach(println)
```

However I am getting error:

> :4: error: ')' expected but '(' found.
>         sqlContext.sql("FROM src SELECT key, value").collect().foreach(println)

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Please specify the folowing:
Which version of Spark? What environment (Shell/Notebook/App?)

Answer (score 0):

You should use standard SQL syntax:

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT key, value FROM src").show()
```

What's more, every sql command should have String as an argument, second command is without ""

```
sqlContext.sql("LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '//filepath' INTO TABLE src")
```

Comment: All things looks good except `sqlContext.sql("LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '//filepath' INTO TABLE src")`

Comment: Nothing is wrong with answer. As per my understanding, he just missed the quotes in said line in the question.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this?

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc) # creating hive context
sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS src (key INT, value STRING)")
sqlContext.sql("LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '//filepath' INTO TABLE src")
val srcRDD = sqlContext.sql("SELECT key, value FROM src")
srcRDD.collect().foreach(println) # printing the data
```

Comment: srcRDD is not a RDD :)

Comment: It will work, my answer is also showing the same errors. However srcRDD is NOT a RDD, but DataFrame. Check type :) Secondly, you should post why something is not working

Comment: sorry spark-1.2.0 it is RDD but in latest version it is DataFrame.